# Why isn't the number of heads in a coin toss computed with replacement?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, combinations

I have searched high and low, but feel like I missing something basic when it comes to counting principles.

Suppose we have a coin that we toss 4 times, and want to count the number of outcomes that have 3 heads. Now, from consulting my textbook, I know the answer is computed using an unordered sequence **without replacement**: $${4\choose 3} = 4$$

But I don't understand why we use an unordered sequence **without replacement** as opposed to an unordered sequence ***with* replacement**:

$$ {n+k-1\choose k} = \frac{(4+3-1)!}{4!(3-1)!} = 15$$

My thought process is that the set of outcomes at each toss is ${\{H, T}\}$. Now naturally once we have tossed once, the outcome for the second toss is still ${\{H, T}\}$, that is we have **replaced** the outcome which we obtained in the first toss to ensure we have a full set to choose from in the second toss. By definition $ {n\choose k} $ on the other hand is used for events with no replacement - but clearly we can  obtain multiple heads or tails during our three toss experiment.

Where in my thought process am I going wrong? Why is the answer 4 and not 15?

Comment: Which $15$ patterns do you see?  List them.  In the usual interpretation, the $4$ patterns would be $HHHT, HHTH, HTHH, THHH$.  Each of these has probability $\frac 1{16}$ so the answer would be $\frac 4{16}$.  What computation would you do?

Comment: @AlexR is correct (+1) for the source of the binomial coefficient ${4 \choose k}$ in the formula for a binomial PDF. However, if you are _performing_ a binomial experiment with a fair coin, then Heads and Tails are sampled **with replacement.** (Otherwise, if you get Heads on the first trial, then only Tails would be left for the second, and the experiment would be over.)

Comment: @BruceET, I think I understand now. So effectively, the experiment is conducted **with replacement**, but the counting is done **without replacement**, and since the counting is all we are concerned about, this is why we use the binomial coefficient. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: That's the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You have 4 coin tosses, which can be thought of as 4 ordered slots (coin values) to fill with either heads or tails.

In this case, out of 4 possible slots, you are selecting 3 slots *without replacement*. So, it's not the coin values themselves, but the slots into which you want the heads to fall into. The chosen slots will contain heads, and the remaining slots will be contain tails.

If you want to compute the probability of such an outcome, than $P(H)=1/2$ for each slot as it should be since each slot is independent.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Your explanation is very helpful. Just so it is clear in my head, we are selecting slots **without replacement**, because once we select the first slot with either heads or tails, we can no longer select that slot, i.e. we cannot replace that slot?

Comment: @Zennith88: yes. You’re saying you want exactly 3 coins to come up as heads, so to make that calculation you need to find the number of ways this can happen and multiply by the probability of each.